# Rotating object breaks limitations/bounds

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I currently use the following logic to rotate an object around another object and set conditions to not exceed 90 degrees or under 1.

```
protected void RotationBounds(){
 bRotateDown = true;
 bRotateUp = true;
 if (_CannonTube.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90)
     bRotateUp = false;
 if (_CannonTube.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z <= 1)
     bRotateDown = false;
 }
```

This allows me to stop the the rotation in a direction once the condition is hit. I then apply the rotation with the following mouse movement controls:

```
protected void RotateCannonMouse(){
if (Input.GetKey ("mouse 0")) {
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") > 0 && bRotateUp == true && bRotateDown == true 
         || Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") > 0 && bRotateUp == false && bRotateDown == true) {
                    transform.RotateAround (_SphereBase.position, -transform.forward,
                    Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * 15);
           }
         if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") < 0  && bRotateUp == true && bRotateDown == true
         || Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") < 0  && bRotateUp == true && bRotateDown == false) {
                     transform.RotateAround (_SphereBase.position, -transform.forward,
                      Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * 15);
       }
}
```

The following functons are then called in the update method.

```
  void Update () {
    RotateCannonMouse();
    RotationBounds();
  }
```

If I rotate the object at a slow/medium speed the conditions hit and it does as I expect. However, if I rotate the object fast it will break through the conditions and mess up the rotation.

I was thinking maybe the update method isn't iterating quickly enough or that I'm rotating the object so fast it skips the bounds values. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

collect all your data, do all your calculations and checks and only then finally rotate if neccessary. you are doing it kinda backwards. you first rotate and then try to clean up the mess. you sure can make it work, but its the hardest way for no reason or gain.

just store the return value of `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")`, add it to your calculated (or even also stored) current rotation, check if its within the bounds (or clamp it) and then, in the very end, decide if and how far you rotate.

(also you dont need to do == with a boolean, its either true or false already -> `if(abool == true)` is the same as `if(abool)` and `if(abool == false)` is the same as `if(!abool)`. ofc it is not *wrong*, it just makes it hard to read)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution we found

```
//If mouse has been clicked
    if (Input.GetKey ("mouse 0")) {

        //Get the angle the mouse wants to move by
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * 5;

        //If the angle is not 0 then we see how much it can move by
        if (mouseY != 0) {

            //Get the current angle of the cannon
            float currentAngle = _CannonTube.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;

            //Work out the new angle that the cannon will go to
            float calcAngle = 0.0f;

            if (mouseY < 0) {
                calcAngle = currentAngle - mouseY;
            } else {
                calcAngle = currentAngle - mouseY;
            }

            //Clamp calcAngle between 5 and 85 
            var newAngle = Mathf.Clamp (calcAngle, 5, 85);

            //calcualte the angle that we are allowed to move by.
            //for example if current angle is 85 and new angle is 85 from the clamp then we move 0 degrees
            var rotateAngle = currentAngle - newAngle;

            //rotate the cannon
            transform.RotateAround (_SphereBase.position, -transform.forward, rotateAngle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: now this looks a lot more readable doesnt it? you dont need the 3rd if though, it does the same no matter if its true or false. just remove the check and leave the calculation. actually you could just initialize calcAngle with the calculated value right away ...